# Ubuntu install on Acer chromebook 13 C810 fails: tegra.conf not found

Tags: system-installation, xorg, chromebook

I'm trying to run Ubuntu on an Acer Chromebook 13 (C810 series) with Tegra K1, following [these instructions](http://www.clifford.at/blog/index.php?/archives/131-Installing-Ubuntu-on-an-Acer-Chromebook-13-Tegra-K1.html)

As the ubuntu-core-14.04 is no longer available and 16.04 doesn't seem to support the GPU of the K1, I changed the package to ubuntu-base-14.04 (I did a [pull request](https://github.com/marcino239/chrubuntu-tegra)).

But when it comes to

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/tegra.conf /tmp/urfs/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

it fails, because there is no `/etc/X11` and the `tegra.conf` can't be found elsewhere on the device. This problem is also mentioned in the comments of the instruction, but unanswered. I'm not sure whether this is a CB5-311 vs C810 problem, as all successes seem to be related to the CB5-311.

Now my question is where can I get the correct `tegra.conf` or what other way is proven to work on the C810 to get an ubuntu (or debian) working with K1 GPU drivers (openGL and openCL needed)?

Comment: Does this mean you succeeded with this guide on the C810? I have no doubt that it's possible on older devices.

Comment: I succeeded with a C710. I don't know what the "normal"  name for your model Chromebook is but, as long as it is supported by SeaBIOS, you should be fine. If it is _not_ supported by SeaBOS, I would look around for another custom ROM/BIOS that is supported and follow its installation instructions. Once you have the ROM in place, the rest of the tutorial is applicable and would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the information I have received you are using a x86 installer and the chrome book is a based on a ARM Cortex CPU with A Tegra K1  GPU there are drivers for the K1 built in to the X86 installer but there are not ones for the ARM Installer (Which is extremely Ironic due to the K1 being ARM Based)

So to sum up The video card does not have any drivers so I would recommend trying to install a server OS then install X11 over that then install unity or the desktop environment you want

Comment: The installation process I'm following is for the Chromebook 720, with the same Tegra K1 SoC. My assumption is that the installer script want to copy needed configuration (and drivers?) from the chromeOS X11 to the ubuntu system, but the new Chromebook doesn't have X11 anymore, so I'd need a different source for them.

Comment: The normal acer c720 has a x86 Intel CPU the Tegra K1 SoC is ARM based the two architectures are completely different get the right installer

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong model number. I don't know where I read it. The old K1 chromebook was CB5-311, it seems. But the problem obviously has nothing to do with x86 architecture. The linked script is for tegra K1 and I have a tegra K1. Everything is fine, except that google [switched from X11 to Freon](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/15/03/09/0220205/google-introduces-freon-a-replacement-for-x11-on-chrome-os) since the last Tegra K1 model (whatever the name may be), so I can't copy the `tegra.conf`. And everything I need is the contents of this file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/xorg-conf/+/stabilize-5696.B/tegra.conf

The file is just included in the xorg config so it should be OK to omit.